# sending mail from java web application

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am working on a web application which can send email. I am using javax mail api. I was able to send email from the test case with the Subject, sender name, Content. But when the application run it send the message with out subject, and content look like this.

```
------=_Part_3_47905596.1416462380132
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test mail Send Succesfully
------=_Part_3_47905596.1416462380132--
```

This is the code I am using.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
String subject = "Test Subject";
String msgContent = "Test mail Send Succesfully";
String senderName = "Jos";
String password = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
String fromEmail = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
String toEmail = "YYYYYYYYYYY@gmail.com";
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            });
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setText(msgContent, "utf-8");
Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart);
message.setContent(multiPart);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail, senderName));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(message);
```

**ADDED DEBUG MESSAGE with out using multipart**

```
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/my-web/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.7.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imaps, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3s, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/my-web/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imaps, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3s, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore, vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc, version=null
DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=smtp; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@17c7ee05; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Oracle
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP uj7sm1724517pac.4 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [201.140.200.84]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [201.140.200.84]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK uj7sm1724517pac.4 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<yyyyyyy@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK uj7sm1724517pac.4 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   yyyyyyy@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead uj7sm1724517pac.4 - gsmtp

Test mail Send Succesfully
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1416479656 uj7sm1724517pac.4 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection uj7sm1724517pac.4 - gsmtp
```

**ADDED DEBUG MESSAGE with multipart**

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=smtp; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@17c7ee05; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Oracle
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP yl6sm1684572pbc.91 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [201.140.200.84]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [201.140.200.84]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK yl6sm1684572pbc.91 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<yyyyyyy@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK yl6sm1684572pbc.91 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   yyyyyyy@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead yl6sm1684572pbc.91 - gsmtp

------=_Part_1_1348144858.1416480282126
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test mail Send Succesfully
------=_Part_1_1348144858.1416480282126--
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1416480266 yl6sm1684572pbc.91 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection yl6sm1684572pbc.91 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The below link describes the cause of this problem

http://yfrankfeng.blogspot.in/2012/07/java-mail-does-not-set-subject-problem.html

Check if there is a dependency `org.apache.openejb`

Try setting the charset of the subject

```
message.setSubject(subject,"utf-8");
```

Comment: set subject method can take only one argument

Comment: No.. it is overloaded to take two as well.. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject(java.lang.String))

Comment: I tried But i still get the same email, without subject

Comment: Instead of `Message message = new MimeMessage(session);` try using `MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);`

Comment: i have done the same way. MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); .. Do i need to add any parameters to my web-server to send the mail

Comment: @jos I don't think so.. as Java mail can be used independently of server I guess...

Comment: @jos By any means are you using this dependency somewhere ?  `org.apache.openejb`

Comment: @jos Check this [LINK](http://yfrankfeng.blogspot.in/2012/07/java-mail-does-not-set-subject-problem.html)

Comment: i had this jar in lib , i removed it javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0, it is because of this jar i was not able to overloaded the  setSubject. now i dont have these jar which you have mensioned

Comment: Thanks your Link saved my time I too had `<groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>` as dependency

Comment: @jos Good to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Java File

```
class MailClient
    extends Authenticator {

public static final int SHOW_MESSAGES = 1;
public static final int CLEAR_MESSAGES = 2;
public static final int SHOW_AND_CLEAR
        = SHOW_MESSAGES + CLEAR_MESSAGES;
public static String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "";
public static String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "";

protected String from;
protected Session session;
protected PasswordAuthentication authentication;

public MailClient(String user, String pass, String host, String port) {
    this(user, pass, host, port, false);
}

public MailClient(String user, String pass, String host, String port, boolean debug) {
    from = user;//user + '@' + host;
    SMTP_AUTH_USER = user;
    SMTP_AUTH_PWD = pass;
    // authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.user", user);
    props.put("mail.host", host);
    props.put("mail.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");//
    props.put("mail.debug", debug ? "true" : "false");
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true" );   
    // props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    //  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();

    session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
    //  System.out.println("mail session created");
}
@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return authentication;
}

public void sendMessage(
        String to, String subject, String content, String from)
        throws Exception {
    //InternetAddress[] replyToAddress = new InternetAddress[1];
    //replyToAddress[0] = new InternetAddress(reply);

    //System.out.println("SENDING message from " + from + " to " + to);
    //System.out.println();

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "test"));

    msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);

    //msg.setReplyTo(replyToAddress);
    msg.setSubject(subject);

    msg.setText(content);

    msg.setContent(content, "text/html");

    Transport.send(msg);

   // System.out.println("Mail sent");
}
private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
        String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
} } public class Mail {
static MailClient client;
public static boolean SendGMail(final String username, final String password, String host, String port, String recipientEmail, String subject, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    boolean status = false;
    client = new MailClient(username, password, host, port);
    try {          
        client.sendMessage(recipientEmail, subject, message, username);
        status = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(Mail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return status;
} }
```

Call Function

```
Mail.SendGMail(appMail, appMailPwd, mailHost, mailPort, mailid, mailSubject, message);
```

Comment: I want to send attachment with the email. so i should send the content as multipart.

Comment: I tried it with out multipart But i still get the same email, without subject

Comment: which jar file you used.

Comment: i am using javax mail 1.4.7 jar

Comment: see my update use mail and activation jar

Comment: thanks it was a dependency issue